# Validation Rule requires update to fields but fields don't need to be changed

Tags: formula, validation-rule

I have a bit of a dilemma. I have a validation rule, whereby when a date field is updated, it then requires two text fields to be updated - which, in theory works well. The issue I am running into is when those two fields already have text entered, and don't need to be updated - the rule won't allow for saving. We have tried clicking in the fields to show activity, re-entering the same data - neither of which allow for saving.

The purpose of the rule is to ensure data is entered into the fields, updated if needed, or reviewed and confirmed correct. Since SFDC still has yet to give a solution for Warning messages, validation rules are all I have to work with. Below is what it currently looks like, and are all custom fields. Any suggestions or workarounds?

```
AND(
    NOT(ISBLANK((Current_Proposal_Date__c))),
    ISCHANGED(Current_Proposal_Date__c),
    OR(
        ISBLANK(TEXT(System_Size__c)),
        NOT(ISCHANGED(System_Size__c))
    ),
    OR(
        ISBLANK(TEXT(Proposal_Transaction_Amount__c)),
        NOT(ISCHANGED(Proposal_Transaction_Amount__c))
    )
)
```

Comment: The phrase *updated if needed* carries a lot of weight here and the community can only guess how you would update from here. How would you know if an update is *not* needed?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your validation rule is too strict and doesn't allow for saving if the text fields already contain data and don't need to be updated. To allow for saving in this scenario, you can modify the rule as follows:

```
AND(
  NOT(ISBLANK(Current_Proposal_Date__c)),
  ISCHANGED(Current_Proposal_Date__c),
  OR(
    ISBLANK(TEXT(System_Size__c)),
    ISCHANGED(System_Size__c)
  ),
  OR(
    ISBLANK(TEXT(Proposal_Transaction_Amount__c)),
    ISCHANGED(Proposal_Transaction_Amount__c)
  )
)
```

This way, if the text fields already contain data, they will be considered as updated and the validation rule won't prevent saving. If the text fields are blank or have been changed, they will be required to be updated before saving.

Comment: For those trying to do a quick skim, the difference here is getting rid of the `NOT()` surrounding the two instances of `ISCHANGED()` in the `OR()`s.

Comment: I don't think this is the solution to OP's problems (it just trades one problem for another). The "you have to make 2 edits to this record" bit is poor from a UX standpoint, and defeats the purpose of the validation rule. Why would users make 2 edits to a record if they can just update the `Current_Proposal_Date__c` and leave the other 2 fields alone? As Adrian has said, I don't think we can give a proper answer here before OP adds details about what _"updated if needed"_ means.

Comment: Plain English:

When date is entered/updated in Current Proposal Date field, the following should occur:

- fill in System Size and Proposal Amount, OR

- update data System Size and Proposal Amount, OR

- confirm data in System Size and Proposal Amount is correct (this is where the problem is occurring). 

 

If the third scenario is true, SFDC does not allow for saving without a visual change in the System and Proposal fields, which isn't what is needed. Even if a cursor is placed in the fields, or an added character like a period to the text fields, it doesn't allow for saving.